# Show that if $a\sin x + b\cos x + ce^x$ is the zero function for constants $a, b, c$ then $a = b = c = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, exponential-function, systems-of-equations

> Suppose that $a\sin x + b\cos x + ce^x$ is the zero function. Prove that $a=b=c=0$.

Does the zero function simply mean that $a\sin x + b\cos x + ce^x = 0$? I am going under the assumption that it is.

[image]

Geometrically speaking, I think it is pretty clear that $a=b=c=0$ must be true if $a\sin x + b\cos x + ce^x = 0$ as there are no x-values that make the equation true otherwise.

Is there a purely algebraic way of saying this that does not utilize showing a graph?

Comment: Zero function means zero for all $x$

Comment: If this function is to be $0$ for any and all $x$, you can substitute any value of $x$ you like into it to get a set of equations that $a$, $b$, and $c$ must obey. For instance, set $x = 0$ to get $b + c = 0$. Do this for other values of $x$ to ultimately obtain a set of linear equations which have $a = b = c = 0$ as the only solution.

Comment: Your problem is equivalent to showing that the functions $\sin(x)$, $\cos(x)$ and $e^x$ are linearly independent functions. One can show this by checking that the Wronskian determinant is identically zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $x=0$.

Thus, $$b+c=0$$

Let $x=\frac{\pi}{2}.$

Thus, $$a+c\cdot e^{\frac{\pi}{2}}=0.$$

Now, substitute $x=-\frac{\pi}{2}$ and solve this system.

We obtain: $$-a+c\cdot e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}=0.$$
Thus,
$$c\left(e^{\frac{\pi}{2}}+e^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\right)=0$$ or
$$c=0,$$ which gives $a=0$ and $b=0$.

Comment: Could you show how the system of equations is setup? My experiences have only been with vectors so far

Comment: @Evan Kim  If $f(x)= a\sin x + b\cos x + ce^x$ and $f(x)=0$ for all real $x$, so $f(0)=f\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=f\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=0$ and it's enough just to solve this system.

Comment: okay thanks for the clarification, I see where you were going with everything now

Comment: @Evan Kim You are welcome! We just proved a linear independence of $\sin$, $\cos$ and an exponential function.

Answer (score 2):

The [Wronskian (determinant)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian) addresses exactly this question, and applies just as well to an arbitary number of ($(n - 1)$-times differentiable) functions: The functions $f_1, \ldots, f_n$ are linearly independent if and only if the determinant $$W[f_1, \ldots, f_n]$$ of the matrix
$$\pmatrix{f_1 & \cdots & f_n \\ f_1' & \cdots & f_n' \\ \vdots & & \vdots \\ f_1^{(n - 1)} & \cdots & f_n^{(n - 1)}}$$ is identically zero.

In our case, $f_1 = \sin, f_2 = \cos, f_3 = \exp$, and computing directly gives
$$W[\sin, \cos, \exp](x) = -2 e^x ,$$
which is not (identically) zero, so the three functions are linearly independent, that is, the only solution $(a, b, c)$ to $$a \sin x + b \cos x + c e^x = 0$$ the zero solution.

Comment: That is interesting. Do you know of any textbooks where I can look up the Wronskian determinant in more detail? Wikipedia description is a bit too complicated for me

Comment: It's standard material in any first course on differential equations. A typical (and I think good) reference is Boyce & DiPrima's *Elementary Differential Equations and Boundary Value Problems"*.

Comment: cool. I am taking a multivariate calculus w/ linear algebra this semester and a differential equations w/ linear algebra as a two-part-sequence next semester so good to have heard of it ahead of time!

Comment: If you're interested in the differential equations approach (which I'd guess from the framing of your question is outside the scope of the course/material from which it's derived), you can approach this problem backward by constructing a linear, homogeneous, ordinary differential equation for which $\sin, \cos, \exp$ span the solution space, and using standard techniques one can find that one such differential equation is $y''' - y'' + y - y = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Given

$a\sin x + b\cos x + ce^x = 0, \tag 1$

we multiply through by $e^{-x}$, which yields

$ae^{-x}\sin x + be^{-x}\cos x + c = 0; \tag 2$

letting $x \to \infty$, we find that

$c = 0; \tag 3$

we are left with

$a\sin x + b\cos x = 0; \tag 4$

now set

$x = \dfrac{\pi}{2}, \tag 5$

and obtain

$a = a\sin \dfrac{\pi}{2} + b\cos \dfrac{\pi}{2} = 0; \tag 6$

thus

$a = 0; \tag 7$

in a similar manner, choosing

$x = 0 \tag 8$

we find

$b = a \sin 0 + b \cos 0 = 0 \tag 9$

as well.

We have in fact established that $\sin x$, $\cos x$, and $e^x$ are linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

If you expand sin, cos and exp into series, and then add them and get one series for the sum, then function is 0 if and only if coefficient on every x^n will be 0, and thus a=b=c=0 will be the only solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $c \neq 0$. Then $x \longmapsto e^x$ is a linear combination of $\sin$ and $\cos$, thus is periodic. It is impossible.

Thus $c=0$, and $a\cos +b\sin=0$. Then evaluate at $0$ and $\pi/2$.